# change numbering of subfloat-environment in memoir

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, memoir, subfloats

I am using the subfloat-environment in memoir, it is working quite well I believe. However, I need to change the numbering of the floats such that it goes vertically, instead of horizontally.

Here is a MWE showing the default horizontal numbering, I would like to change it to vertical (shown in the comments):

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}} %A
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}} %C
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}} %E
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}} %B
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}} %D
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}} %F 
  \caption{Round}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping them inside `minipages` worked for me.

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\\ %A
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}} %C
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\\ %E
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}} %B
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\\ %D
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}} %F 
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Round}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice solution. Is there a way to get two columns with three pictures in each? So first column is (a,b,c) and second column is (d,e,f)?

Comment: @BillyJean    Insert as many figures you want in each `minipage` with `\\` between them to break the line.